# don't be that away -- what does that exactly mean?

Tags: progressive-aspect, aspect, linking-verbs

From a science fiction movie entitled *The Mist* (2007):

> — Nobody else heard that sound?
>   — What sound?
>   — I don't know. Like a weird noise. Back there in the dark. Like something was, like, pressing against the door.
>   — Did you hear it before the lights went out or after?
>   — No, only after. But, look, I heard it, okay?
>   — Nobody's calling you a liar.
>   — That's what it sounds like.
>   — No, no, no, no. Now, **don't be that away**, Mr Drayton. You had a scare, no doubt. What say we all go check it out?

What does that exprssion exactly mean?

Comment: I think it is supposed to be "Now, don't be that **way**.

Comment: Or it could be "Don't be that-a-way" which I've heard in some rural dialects. If so, it means the same thing as "Don't be that way."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Don't be that way* means *Don't **behave** that way*.

When *be* is a finite verb, this sense of the word is expressed with the progressive construction.

> George **is** a jerk *means that* 'jerkness' *is a permanent property of George, but*
>   George **is being a jerk *means that George is temporarily behaving like a jerk.*

In effect, we compel the verb *be* to act as an activity instead of a copula, and its complement has an adverbial rather than a nominal or adjectival force. Consequently, in questions and commands it takes adverbials of manner where as a copula it would normally take pronominal complements:

> *Not*
>   <sup>∗</sup>**What** is George being tonight? Don't be **that**, George.
>   *but*
>   <sup>ok</sup>**How** is George being tonight? Don't be **that way**, George.